# how to display titleForHeaderInSection

Tags: iphone

I got array which has one,two,three,four,five. values..
in my array....says countListArray.

I need to display this countlistarray has titleForHeaderInSection....

for each section i need to display 6 cell...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement table view data source and delegate methods.

for name of section use this

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
 return [yourArray objectAtIndex:section];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to handle titleForRow:inSection message. Or, do you have any problems with that?